# OSM change default marker look

Tags: java, markers, jmapviewer

I am working on a desktop Java application that uses OSM maps and jMapViewer api in order to view, add Markers etc on the map.

[jMapViewer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer#Development)

As you can see at the link above, the markers are represented as dots. To be specific, there is a class "MapMarkerDot" that draws these dots every time I add a marker.

This looks really bad in my eyes. Is there any way to replace these dots with something more "good looking"?

A solution would be to download a marker image and place the image instead of drawing the dot, but I can't figure out how to do this. Any suggestions/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own class that implements the MapMarker interface and renders markers differently https://josm.openstreetmap.de/doc/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/MapMarkerDot.html

You might also  consider to switch to [JXMapViewer2](https://github.com/msteiger/jxmapviewer2).

Comment: Hi @MaM, if I use JXMapViewer2, how can I draw a dot? Thanks!